# Ubuntu 17.10 display gets corrupted after awhile, sometimes

Tags: xorg

My Panasonic Toughbook (32-bit) running 17.10 (I use Xorg as Wayland has problems with cursor being weird and unusable) will boot up fine and most of the time all is fine (and awesome!)... BUT, about every third time or so it will boot up, you'll be browsing or looking at files in nautilus, or sometimes just doing nothing, and the screen will turn into this kaleidescope of colors, go blank for a couple of seconds, the back to the horizontal kaleidescope lines of color, go blank, lines of color, etc. Nothing except hitting the power button and rebooting gets it back to normal.

Only started this about a couple of weeks after upgrade to 17.10. Did my video card suddenly decide to begin flaking out coincidentally after the upgrade, or did one of the updates in the past week or so mess up the video driver or something? I did check to see if display (settings, devices, color) was calibrated (used D65).

Comment: I don't know whether it's helpful, but it seems Ubuntu has dropped 32bit images. Ubuntu 17.10 was released with only a 64bit version. I would highly recommend lighter Ubuntu flavours (Lubuntu/Xubuntu/Ubuntu MATE) for a 32bit computers.

Comment: If being 32-bit (processor) an issue - why is problem 'sometimes'?
(processor is 32-bit - so wouldn't images 32 or 64 or 128-bit irrelevant as far as a stable display?)

Comment: The laptop uses an ATI Mobility Radeon 9000 graphics card that shares 64 MB with the system's RAM, if that helps... adjusted the brightness down a little bit hoping that helps ;-)

Comment: OK - so whatever it was causing the screen corruption seems to have stopped... either a recent update fixed a previous update that allows the video card to function 'normally' again.... or adjusting the brightness from 70% to 60% put less stress on this old laptop's video card and somehow that did it - just glad I don't have to keep holding down the power button as my only option when this happens (can't do anything when vid goes down) ~ reminds me of the old Windoz95 days :-\

Comment: So after over two weeks w/no corrupted screen problem, this issue returns and been at it for the last two days (holdin' down the ol' power button gets it to stop/reboot) - another ubutu update messin' things up?
I really yearn for the ol' Win95 daze...

... wonder what MINT is like?

Comment: Older laptops, what can you do? Think I've found the culprit - seems the laptop pad I use to raise the laptop and allow air flow below it was causing it to over heat ... one of the pad nubs was located under the part of the case where the CPU is located insulating it from venting and allowing it to heat up excessively. Noticed my 'Psensor' app was showing system temps over 205F a lot, and rebooting temporarily would cool it down, but if the room was heated too much (in winter this happens sometimes) the added heat pushed the CPU to lose semi-conduction - shifted pad and now <150F and fine!